# How to get image path from JSON file?

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

I am just trying to display an image from a JSON file:

```
[
    {
        "Images" : "images/examples.jpg"
    }
]
```

But JSON does not accept the path as a path but as a string. Is there any way to display the image?

Comment: "Is there any way to display the image?" means ? Where you want to display image?

Comment: So you read the string, create an image, set the source, add it to the page.....

Comment: Display it in my HTML page, <div class="displayimages">{{Images}}</div>

Comment: Try <img src="{{Images}}">

Comment: yes, create a HTML image element and put the URL as the "src" of the image. Just like any other image in a HTML document. The only difference really is you didn't hardcode the URL (or even the image element). Hard to believe you couldn't have googled this already tbh, or something very close to it.

Comment: Also, no idea what this means: "does not accept the path as a path but as a string". What else is a path except a string describing a location? It's not a data type of its own. And "JSON" itself doesn't accept or reject anything...it's just a data transmission format. Perhaps you're referring to some code you're having a problem with...if so, you should probably show it to us so we can help you fix it.

Comment: @Cakan Thanks a lot this actually worked!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how you are processing the JSON but the path of the image is all you need. You would simply then use that path to show the image.

In the example below I used javascript to parse the image path and inject it into the image source.

The key here is you need to somehow get the path of the image into the `img` tag. 
`<img src="{{json.Images}}">`

```js
var json = '{"Images" : "https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/sample.jpg"}';

var jsonObject = JSON.parse(json);

document.getElementById("someImage").src = jsonObject.Images;
```

```html
<img id="someImage" src="">
```

Answer (score 0):

Below an example using an image from placeholder.com

```js
const a = [{
  "Images": "https://via.placeholder.com/100x100"
}];

// Store reference to image tag
const image = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];

a.map(function(img) {
  // Here just assigning the single image URL 
  image.src = img.Images;
})
```

```html
<img src="">
```